# Java application auto-shutting instead of streaming data in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ais

(This is a follow-up of my previous post) When I try to run my project for fetching ais data and then storing it in database, this generates and the program auto-shuts down without streaming data instead of streaming the data constantly to the database.

```
313 [main] INFO com.example.demo.DemoApplication - Starting DemoApplication using Java 21 with PID 18304 (E:\Programming\sdf\demo\target\classes started by Asus in E:\Programming\sdf\demo)
313 [main] INFO com.example.demo.DemoApplication - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
644 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
662 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 12 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
864 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
1066 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@118102ee
1067 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2024-02-15 14:37:04.462] - 18304 INFO [main] --- org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2024-02-15 14:37:04.522] - 18304 INFO [main] --- org.hibernate.Version: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final
[2024-02-15 14:37:04.560] - 18304 INFO [main] --- org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator: HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
1484 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo - No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
[2024-02-15 14:37:05.158] - 18304 INFO [main] --- org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator: HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
1835 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
1964 [main] INFO com.example.demo.DemoApplication - Started DemoApplication in 1.9 seconds (process running for 2.382)
1969 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
1971 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
1974 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Note: All the above info is displayed in red, and not white like it is normally. (I am using IntelliJ, if that matters)

Comment: And it should do that because of what? YOu only dump your startup logs and what should do the streaming according to you/